# how to set a form in secondary screen

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I have written a program (C#) which loads a form.  On the primary screen it displays different text when I click OK.  But the problem is... I am working with dual monitor, so when I load a form on the primary screen and drag it to secondary screen and click OK, it automatically moves back to the primary screen.

I have written a method which determines which screen the form is currently loaded on, which is working fine. However, when I tried to relocate it to the secondary screen, it no longer works (it's still moving back to the primary screen).  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is my code:

```
if(Currentscreen == "primary")
{
    forma.showDialog(this);//this is ok showing form on main screen
}
else
{
    int showOnMonitor = 1;
    Screen[] scr;
    scr = Screen.AllScreens;
    forma.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
    forma.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left, sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);  //this line should relocate it on secondary screen
    forma.showDialog(this);  //but its again loading on Primary monitor
}
```

Comment: if(Currentscreen ="primary")                                                                    {                                                                    forma.showDialog(this);//this is ok showing form on mainscreen              } else { int showOnMonitor = 1; Screen[] scr; scr = Screen.AllScreens; forma.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; forma.Location = new Point(sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left, sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top);//this line should relocate it on secondary screen forma.showDialog(this);//but its again loading on Primary monitor }

Comment: please add relevant tags like which project you are working on, framework, etc.

Comment: .Net 4.0, visual studio 2012, c#

Comment: I guess the project is Win Forms?

Comment: yup got any solution Rohit??

Comment: its not  working as well

Comment: what didn't work? There are two suggestions in that post, setting the `StartPosition` to manual, and setting the location using `Screen.AllScreens[1].WorkingArea.Location;`. Did you try both of these and neither worked?

Comment: yes i tried both but every time fome come back to Promaryscreen.

Comment: try this:
1. make property - StartPosition to Manual
2. forma.Location = Screen.AllScreens[numOfScreen].WorkingArea.Location; // numOfScreen=1